# How to send .xls file to Microsoft Excel app for editing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, excel, ipad

I want to send .xls file which is stored in my app's Document folder to Microsoft Excel app for editing. How can I achieve this?

I am guessing that I have to call openURL method of UIApplication class but the question is with what scheme and parameters?

All I want to achieve is to edit .xls files on iPad which are stored in my app's Document directory, it doesn't really matter what app is used to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's special view controller for this - UIDocumentInteractionController.

Look at [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html)

Comment: UIDocumentInteractionController looks to be most effective way to send content to another app on iOS. I haven't tried it yet for Excel files but have seen it working with pdf files.